# Find k for this matrix multiplication

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have these three matrices:

```
A = [4 1 0;6 k 4], B = [-2 -1;3 1;-2 4], AB = [-5 -3;-20 10]
```

I want to know how I can use MatLab to find k, if `AB = A * B`.

I tried this:

```
fsolve(@(x) mtimes([4 1 0;6 x 4],[-2 -1;3 1;-2 4]),[-5 -3;-20 10]);
```

But that did not work out. Any ideas how I can do this?

Comment: The same homework question was posted on SO this week. You can find it yourself or ask you classmate who posted it for the solution.

Comment: Can you post a link of that question?

Comment: @L.Mermans Unfortunatedly stackoverflow is not your google service.

Comment: I don't really know why people are down-voting this question, Of course I tried searching it first but it's not easy (go try and find it yourself)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick here is to define k as symbolic variable, and then use `solve` to solve the equality you defined. You'll notice easily just by looking at `A*B` that the solution should be 0.

```
syms k
A = [4 1 0;6 k 4];
B = [-2 -1;3 1;-2 4];
AB = [-5 -3;-20 10];

A*B

solve(A*B==AB)
```

Comment: Thanks, all this time I had the Maple Toolbox installed which overrides the built-in solve function, hence I was not able to do this.